# Ruby Sinatra Submitting Passwords

Tags: ruby, sinatra, password-protection, secure-coding

I am creating a small Sinatra application which will have login functionality. This would be the first time I have done this in ruby and wanted some advice when posting passwords from a html form. What would be the best and most secure way to do this.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: I bet there is a lot of methods to do this. Try, for example, use `sinatra-authentication` https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication

Comment: "login functionality" means you want people to authenticate to your Sinatra app, not have the Sinatra app connect to something else where it has to authenticate, right?

Answer (score 2):

Posting password from a HTML form in a secure way is not, exactly, a Ruby/Sinatra issue. It is a set of best practices take on all components of your stack.

As long as I remember, these are the items that come to my mind:

1. For transfer sensible data **always** use HTTPS.
2. **Never** save clean password on your database. Always use a Hash algorithm with salt http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm.
3. Impose some constraints to the password, like: minimum length, force letters and numbers, etc.
4. Avoid to log sensible data (e-mail, password).